# Memory leak in msxml6, MRE

Tags: memory-leaks, com, atl, msxml, msxml6

MRE:

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <MsXml2.h>
#include <atlcomcli.h>

#include <fstream>

int main() {

    std::string strFileName( "xml.xml" );
    std::ofstream outFile( strFileName );
    outFile << "<root><n1><n2><n3><n4><n5/></n4></n3></n2></n1></root>";
    outFile.close();

    while ( CoInitializeEx( nullptr, COINIT_APARTMENTTHREADED ) == S_OK ) { 
        {
            CComPtr<IXMLDOMDocument2> spIXMLDOMDocument2;
            HRESULT hr = spIXMLDOMDocument2.CoCreateInstance( L"Msxml2.DOMDocument.6.0", nullptr, CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER );
            if ( hr == S_OK ) {
                VARIANT_BOOL vbSuccess = VARIANT_FALSE;
                CComVariant ccvarXmlSource( strFileName.c_str() );
                hr = spIXMLDOMDocument2->load( ccvarXmlSource, &vbSuccess );
            } else exit( 0 );
        }
        CoUninitialize();
        Sleep( 0 );
    }

}
```

The code is just an infinite loop of `CoInitializeEx` `CoCreateInstance` `load` `Release` and `CoUninitialize`, (with the help of `CComPtr`)

Release Build, x64, Visual Studio 2017, Windows 10 (1809).
On my laptop, this leaks several tens of KB per minute.
Process Explorer showed me private bytes at 2,5Mo at the start, and at 19Mo 3 hours later.

C:\Windows\System32\msxml6.dll version: 6.30.17763.437

UPDATE: Threaded MRE

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <MsXml2.h>
#include <atlcomcli.h>

#include <fstream>
#include <thread>

void ThreadFunction( ) {

        if ( CoInitializeEx( nullptr, COINIT_APARTMENTTHREADED ) != S_OK ) exit ( 0 );
        {
            CComPtr<IXMLDOMDocument2> spIXMLDOMDocument2;
            HRESULT hr = spIXMLDOMDocument2.CoCreateInstance( L"Msxml2.DOMDocument.6.0", nullptr, CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER );
            if ( hr == S_OK ) {
                VARIANT_BOOL vbSuccess = VARIANT_FALSE;
                CComVariant ccvarXmlSource( "xml.xml" );
                hr = spIXMLDOMDocument2->load( ccvarXmlSource, &vbSuccess );
            } else exit( 0 );
        }
        CoUninitialize();

}

int main() {

    std::ofstream outFile( "xml.xml" );
    outFile << "<root><n1><n2><n3><n4><n5/></n4></n3></n2></n1></root>";
    outFile.close();

    while ( true ) {

        std::thread oneThread( ThreadFunction );
        oneThread.join();

        Sleep( 0 );

    }

}
```

Can you reproduce?

Comment: CoInitializeEx is not supposed to be ran in a while loop, just once per thread. Put it out and everything will be fine. PS: In general, you should test SUCCEEDED(hr), not hr == S_OK.

Comment: @SimonMourier I tried to make my MRE as small and simple as possible. Running the offending code in a function with a single `CoInitializeEx`/`CoUninitialize` and then looping in the main thread with a simple `std::thread` creation, followed by `join` doesn't change anything. I will update the question with a threaded version of the MRE.

Comment: Ok, the sample seems more reasonable, and I do reproduce the private bytes going slowly up, caused by the load method. I have version 6.30.18362.239. Only Microsoft can help with that, if you really want to stick to MSXML6. You could try Windows' XmlLite if you have rather simple xml requirements.